# I'd'd like to take a list of strings, find them in another csv file and print a field from the matching line

Tags: python, csv, text

I have a large `.csv` file with a few thousand lines and a handful of columns. For simplicity, it looks a little like

```
Name, ID
One, 1
Two, 2
```

I'd like to write a script which takes a list of strings, treating each line as a separate entity, and finds the line containing a match to that entry on the list.
Once it's found the line which matches, I'd like to print one of the fields to a new file.

For example, given a list:

```
1
2
```

I'd like to be able to produce a file containing the associated 'Name' value.

So far I have no issues with reading in my list file like:

```
list_file = sys.argv[1]
f = open(list_file, 'r+')
ListOfNames = f.read()
```

But I'm a little confused about how to proceed. Previously, when I've written similar codes, I've prompted the user for a string using `raw_input()` and simply searched through the `csv` file for a match like so:

```
 def Return_Name(ID):
        file_csv = csv.DictReader(open('file.csv'))
            for row in file_csv:
                if row['ID'] == ID:
                     print row['Name']
```

But I'm unsure of how to do this whilst iterating over a list. Would anyone be able to help?

Apologies that this question isn't the most structured, but any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read in the list of IDs, this should do the trick perfectly:

```
list_ids = [line.strip() for line in open('list.txt').xreadlines()]
```

And combining that with what you posted:

```
for id in list_ids:
    Return_Name(id)
```

Cheers

Comment: This will cause the CSV file to be opened and read for every single ID.

Comment: This helped me the most thank you :) WreckeR has a good point which may become problematic with larger lists but for my purposes this is great.

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close. change `Return_Name` to take a list of IDs.

```
def Return_Names(ID_list):
    names = []
    file_csv = csv.DictReader(open('file.csv'))
        for row in file_csv:
            if row['ID'] in ID_list:
                 # print row['Name']
                 names.append(row['Name'])
    return names
```

Comment: Thank you :) this helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the "in" operator?

```
>>> id = 3
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> l2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> id in l1
True
>>> id in l2
False
```

So, you'd check if your row['ID'] is in the list of identifiers that you have.